# Is the exams r package still available? I can't install on a mac lion 10.7.5

Tags: r, r-exams

Not able to find installation of "exams" R package . It's still available? or  deprecated?
Not on CRAN. Please help

Comment: You will have to compile it on your own. See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exams/index.html

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the check log -- it might conceivably be temporarily hung up in a 2.15.3 -> 3.0.0 transition??

Comment: Current CRAN check log says error in a Latex construction with the examples section with R 3.0.0. "Error in texi2dvi(out_tex[j], pdf = TRUE, clean = TRUE, quiet = quiet) :
Running 'texi2dvi' on 'exam1.tex' failed."

Answer (score 4):

I just compiled it from source and it appears that t has no C code so you can probably just do this:

```
 install.packages("exams", type="source")
```